# $a^{m+n} = a^m*a^n$ where $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: real-analysis, integers

I can use the exponents laws only $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$,  and need to prove them for $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

note that $0 \neq a \in \mathbb{R}$

I proved some cases (mainly the trivial ones) and I'm having a hard time proving this case:

Assuming $m<0 \wedge n>0$ and $\left | n \right | > \left | m \right |$ we know that $(m+n) \in \mathbb{N}$

I was thinking about expressing $n+m$ as $k\in\mathbb{N}$ but then I need to handle the cases where $k = 1$ and $k > 1$

I started with $a^{m+n} = \frac{1}{a^{-m-n}}$ but then again I get that $-m \in\mathbb{N}$ and that $-n<0$ so I can't seem to apply any exponent rules with the naturals.

How should I approach this?

**edit**:

Would it be legit performing:

$a^{m+n} = \frac{1}{a^{-m-n}} = \frac{1}{a^{-m}*\frac{1}{a^{n}}} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{a^m}*\frac{1}{a^n}} = a^m*a^n$

Comment: Look at $a^{n+m} a^{-m}=a^n$

Comment: @JulianMejia how about: 
$\frac{1}{a^{-m-n}} = \frac{1}{a^{-m-n}*\frac{a^n}{a^n}} = \frac{1}{a^{-m}*\frac{1}{a^n}} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{a^{m}}*\frac{1}{a^{n}}} = a^m*a^n$

Comment: I think you would be less confused if you always consider $m,n$ positive or zero, and use $-n$ and $-m$ to represent negative exponents.

Comment: @zwim is the equation that I wrote in the comment above legit tho?

Comment: It is not, because you said $(m+n)\in \mathbb N$ so you do $a^{-m-n}*a^n=a^{-m-n+n}$ with one exponent negative $-m-n<0$ and the other one $n>0$ positive. You use the result you want to prove in your proof.

Comment: @zwim yeah, you're right.

Comment: @zwim Last shot: $a^{m+n} = a^{m+n}*a^{m-m} = a^{m+n-m}*a^{m} = a^{n}*a^{m}$

Comment: Well, it works, but it is preferable to write it $a^{m+n}*1=a^{m+n}*\dfrac{a^m}{a^m}=(a^{m+n}*a^{-m})*a^m=a^{m+n-m}a^m=a^na^m$ else we can wonder how you go from $a^{m-m}$ to implicitly split it after the second $=$ sign. The idea (exploiting $1=a^0$) is exactly the same I used in my presentation.

Answer (score 1):

Defining $a^{-k}:=\frac{1}{a^k}$ for $k>0$, we first prove $a^{m+1}=a^m a$ for all $m\in\Bbb Z$: the desired result is the definition of $a^{m+1}$ for $m\ge 0$, is trivial if $m=-1$, and extends to $m=-k$ for all $k>0$ viz. $$a^{-k+1}=\frac{1}{a^{k-1}}=\frac{a}{a^k}=a^{-k}a.$$Now your original problem is solved for $n=1$, all $n\ge 1$ follow from the inductive step $$a^{m+l+1}=a^ma^l\cdot a=a^m a^{l+1},$$and $n=0$ is trivial. Finally, if $n=-k$ with $k>0$ then $$a^m a^n=\frac{a^m}{a^k}=a^{m-k},$$with the last $=$ following from $a^sa^k=a^{s+k}$ with $s:=m-k$. This is valid by a previous step because $k>0$.

Comment: Thanks, would you mind telling if my way in the edit section is legit?

Comment: @vpam Your edit goes from the both-nonnegative case to both-negative case, but you need an extra trick when the signs of $m,\,n$ differ, viz. Julian Mejia's comment.

Comment: Maybe $\frac{1}{a^{-m-n}} = \frac{1}{a^{-m-n}*\frac{a^n}{a^n}} = \frac{1}{a^{-m}*\frac{1}{a^n}} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{a^{m}}*\frac{1}{a^{n}}} = a^m*a^n$ ?

Answer (score 0):

**Important note:** I consider always $m,n,k\in\mathbb N$, and use $-n,-m,-k$ for negative exponents.

If both negative exponents then $$a^{-m-n}=(\frac 1a)^{m+n}\color{red}=(\frac 1a)^n(\frac 1a)^m=a^{-n}a^{-m}$$

$\color{red}=\quad$ base $\frac 1a\neq 0$ and $m,n$ positive exponents.

If one is negative and the other positive, since the expression is symmetric we don't lose in generality assuming $m\le n$.

Then consider $n-m=k\ge 0$.

$$\require{cancel}a^{-n}=a^{0-n}=a^{k-k-n}=a^{\cancel{n}-m-k-\cancel{n}}=a^{-m-k}\color{blue}=a^{-m}a^{-k}$$

$\color{blue}=\quad$ base $a\neq 0$ and $-m,-k$ both negative exponents.

Rearranging gives $a^k=a^na^{-m}$ which is the desired result.

Comment: if $-k$ is negative how can u justify $a^{-m-k}\color{blue}=a^{-m}a^{-k}$ ?
you can't operate that move, can you?

Comment: this was the purpose of the first step, with both exponents negative.

Comment: But you defined $0 \leq k$ , so you can't use exponent laws on $-k$

Comment: I use it on $-m$ and $-k$ both negative. Which I proved on step 1 that I can do the split move via the use of $\frac 1a$. $a^{-m-k}=(\frac 1a)^{m+k}=(\frac 1a)^m(\frac 1a)^k=a^{-m}a^{-k}$